# Lyx is ignoring typewriter font setting for program listings

Tags: fonts, listings, lyx, typewriter

I'm using Lyx's **Insert|Program Listing** to insert a code listing into my document. Unfortunately, Lyx seems to ignore the Typewriter font selection I made in **DocumentOptions** under **Fonts ⇒ Typewriter**. Interestingly enough, typewriter font does come out correctly elsewhere, but not in program linstings.

Can someone help me figure out why? I'm using Lyx 2.0.2 and am using XeTeX for output.

Comment: Have you changed the listing to actually use typewriter fonts? By default, they are not used.

Comment: No, I haven't. I assumed they'd be used automatically. If that's not the case, how do I make this setting document-wide? Also, I think the letter spacing in program listings is wrong (wider than normal), is there any way to get it to 'default' levels?

Comment: I added a suggestion about the spacing issue to my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Program listings does not actually use the typewriter font family by default, so you have to change this in the settings. To change it for a single listing, right click it, choose Settings and select Typewriter as Font family.

[image]

To make it a global change, go to Document --> Settings --> Listings, and type in the following option:

```
basicstyle={\ttfamily}
```

For the spacing, try adding

```
columns=fullflexible
```

to the options list for listings. I'm not entirely sure about this, though the different choices for `columns` is described in the [`listings` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/listings) (`listings` is the package used for these program listings), section **2.10
Fixed and flexible columns**.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. What about letter spacing - can that be fixed too? Or am I imagining things?

Comment: Actually, I've just tried `\basicstyle{\ttfamily}` and XeTeX gave me an `Undefined control sequence`.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk There is no backslash before `basicstyle` and an `=` after.

Comment: Whoops, my bad.

Comment: For spacing, setting `basewidth=0.45em` will reduce the inter-letter spacing from a ridiculous `0.6em` to a more compact width, all while preserving the fixed width (whereas `columns=fullflexible` wrecks the spacing). To change the font size, try, for example, `\basicstyle{\ttfamily,\small}`.

Answer (score 2):

I still use LyX 1.6, the more recent version available for Windows 2000 (which I have in a couple of PCs). In LyX 1.6.10 you don't find the "Listings" module in the "Document->Settings" menu. So you solve this issue by adding

```
\lstset{basicstyle={\ttfamily},columns=fullflexible}
```

to the "Latex Preamble" box in the "Document->Settings" menu.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).