# How to include program listings in C# with custom font and syntax highlighting in LyX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, listings, lyx, highlighting

I'm rather new to LaTeX and use LyX editor to create my documents. There are similar questions but none of them answer how to do that in LyX. I am wondering, how to include a program listing in C/C++/C# which would satisfy these conditions:

- Syntax highlighting, example:

[image: Highlighting example]

- Custom font (I've set a non-TeX Consolas font to be used as "Typewriter" font but nothing happens in program listing even though it works when used inline i.e. \mathtt{Foo}
- It would be a bonus, if I could include the code as a file, like I did now (Insert -> File -> Child Document -> Program Listing)
- Line numbers are also a bonus.

So far, what I could come up with was:
[image: TeX example]

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: So you want syntax highlighting and *verbatim* environment is not good for you...right?

Comment: @MattAllegro Insert --> Program Listing in LyX uses the `listings` package.

Comment: Regarding typewriter font: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53260/lyx-is-ignoring-typewriter-font-setting-for-program-listings/53269#53269 `listings` also has the ability to display line numbers, add the option `numbers=left`. (Meant to add this sooner, but forgot, sorry about that.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Can you post an answer, or do you know a question of which this one is a duplicate?

Comment: @Jubobs No clear dupe I think, so I answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no one duplicate of your question, though most parts of the answer can be found in other questions, such as

- [How do I add syntax coloring to my C++ source code in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68091/how-do-i-add-syntax-coloring-to-my-c-source-code-in-beamer)
- [Lyx is ignoring typewriter font setting for program listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53260/lyx-is-ignoring-typewriter-font-setting-for-program-listings/53269#53269)

When you do Insert --> Program Listing, or Insert --> File --> Child document --> Program listing, LyX uses the features of the `listings` package to typeset the source code. The `listings` output can be customized in many different ways, which are described in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/listings).

You can add customizations for each listing, or do it globally. To do it for a single listing, right click it and choose *Settings*. If it is a child document, add options to the *More parameters* box. If it is plain listing, you'll find this same box under the Advanced tab in the settings. To do it globally, which is likely what you want, go to Document --> Settings --> Listings.

Parameters are entered as `key=value` pairs, just as you see in the questions linked to above, but in the LyX settings you add one parameter per line, commas are not needed. Syntax highlighting is covered by the first of the questions above. To add line numbering, add `numbers=left`, which adds the numbers to the left of the line, and you may want something like `numberstyle=\tiny` which sets the numbers in a small size.

A complete set of parameters, that you can copy-paste to Document --> Settings --> Listings, is

```
basicstyle={\ttfamily}
commentstyle={\color{green}\ttfamily}
keywordstyle={\color{blue}\ttfamily}
language={C++}
morecomment={[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}}
numbers=left
numberstyle={\tiny}
stringstyle={\color{red}\ttfamily}
```

You may also be interested in `columns=fullflexible` and `breaklines=true`.