# How can I insert a Matlab code in Lyx easily

Tags: lyx, matlab

I have a .m file with Matlab code and I want to paste it in Lyx. How can I do this easily?

Comment: Do you mean to make to put the Matlab code inside a "verbatim environment" like listing? If So, Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/what-can-i-use-to-typeset-matlab-code-in-my-document helps?

Answer (score 9):

I'd recommend using the `matlab-prettifier` package (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/586), which is really just provides a style for the `listings` package. This will give you good highlighting of Matlab code, while still enabling you to use the built-in stuff in LyX related to code listings (if you so desire).

To use the package, take these two steps:

1. Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble: Add

   ```
   \usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
   ```
2. Document --> Settings --> Listings: Add

   ```
   style=Matlab-editor
   ```

Now, there are two different methods for getting code into LyX. Either input a file directly, or copy-paste code from Matlab:

#### Input file

In your document, do Insert --> File --> Child Document. Choose *Program listing* as "Include type", click the Browse button, and find an `.m` that you want to include:

[image: insert child document dialog in LyX]

You can write caption and label right away, if you like, or do it later by right-clicking on the inset and choosing settings.

#### Copy-pasting code

The key-thing if you do want to copy-paste code into a listing (made with Insert --> Program listing, or ERT), is that you need to use *paste special*, i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> or Edit --> Paste special --> Plain text. If you don't, line breaks in the code will not be preserved.

For the code environment, you can use [Mark Pace's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388335/586) in an ERT directly, or you can use Insert --> Program listing, which inserts a `lstlisting` environment, just as Mark's code. If you right-click in that inset and choose settings,

[image: accessing settings dialog of code listing inset in LyX]

you can adjust some things. To adjust settings that are not available from the first tab of the settings dialog, go to the *Advanced* tab, and write them as key=value pairs in the right panel. This includes things like caption and label.

One caveat here: if you use this method to insert a listing with a caption, you will not be able to access that label in LyX's cross-reference system. That is, if you do Insert --> Cross-reference, the code listings will *not* show up in the list of labels. A child document-listing on the other hand, will show up. (You can circumvent that by adding a new label via Insert --> Label inside a LyX note, made with Insert --> Note --> LyX Note, but it's more of a hassle.)

Comment: Thanks! I used the special paste with the code provided by Mark Pace and it worked perfectly! :D

Comment: @Moltimor If you prefer to avoid ERTs for some reason, then use Insert -> Program listing instead, which does exactly the same, but you need to go into the advanced settings of the inset (via right click) to set the optional parameters (`caption`, `label`, etc.).

Comment: @Moltimor I extended my answer a little bit, by the way.

Comment: Is there a way to add a frame to program listing enviornment?

Comment: @FreeZe Add `frame=single` to Document -> Settings -> Listings, I think.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
\usepackage{listings}
...
\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab]{//--PATH--//YourNameHere.m}
```

However I would rather use:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
[
language=Matlab
,caption={CAPTION}
,label=LABEL]
%%%%% COPY CODE HERE %%%%%
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Note that in LyX you can insert a listing with Insert > Program Listing

Comment: Thanks. I tried both method, but in the first one I get some errors and in the second one (using "insert program listing" ) I don't get a text with proper format when compiling

Comment: @Moltimor You can of course change the format of the listings (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53260/lyx-is-ignoring-typewriter-font-setting-for-program-listings/53269#53269), but what is "proper format"?

Comment: I copy de text from Matlab and paste it in LyX, but I don't get the right spacing bwetween lines and commentaries. It is pasted as plane text and it's illegible